# Angular Directive to modify embed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, embed, firebase

I am trying to modify an embeded object by using Angular Directive.  I am having a hard time getting the directive to work.

This is the object code.

```
<object width="250" height="40">
    <param name="movie" value="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="window">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs=26593443&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0">
    <embed src="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250"height="40"flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs=26593443&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="window"/>
</object>
```

What I am trying to do is have the songIDs dynamically defined.  I have tried

```
    <object width="250" height="40">
        <param name="movie" value="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="window">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <param name="flashvars"value="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs=" + {{bpmSong[0].$id}} + "&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0">
        <embed src="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"width="250"height="40"flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs=" + {{bpmSong[0].$id}} + "&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="window"/>
    </object>
```

basiclly I have a number that is `{{bpmSong[0].$id}}` and I am trying to use to define as the SongID.

I think a directive is the solution I need but I haven't been able to get a directive to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE with attempt from @JayMc answer.  I also changed the src so that i didnt get the syntax error.  Still doesnt work.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="GrooveApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="radio">
        <button class="btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="count = count - 1" ng-init="count=0">Previous</button>
        <flash-widget songID='{{bpmSong[0].$id}}' ></flash-widget>
        <button class="btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="count = count + 1">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{bpmSong[count].$id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module("GrooveApp", ["firebase"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $firebase) {
        var ref = new Firebase("/bpm_playlist");
        var sync = $firebase(ref);
        // create a synchronized array for use in our HTML code
        $scope.bpmSong = sync.$asArray();
    })
    .directive('flashWidget', function(){

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                width:'=',
                height:'=',
                src: '=',
                songID: '='
            },
            template: '<object width="250" height="40">'+
            '<param name="movie" value="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf">'+
                '<param name="wmode" value="window">'+
            '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">'+
                '<param name="flashvars"value="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs="{{songId}}"&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0">'+
            '<embed src="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"width="250"height="40"flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs="{{songId}}"&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="window"/>'+
                '</object>'
        }
    });
```

Comment: You've forgotten to concat your strings in `template:` with a `+`

Comment: I did and I moved the src and I dont get a syntax error anymore but the flash player says there is no song

Answer (score 0):

Try a directive like the following, this is untested.

```
.directive('flashWidget', function(){

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        width:'=',
        height:'=',
        src: '=',
        songID: '='
    },
    template: '<object width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}">'+
                '<param name="movie" value="{{src}}">'+
                '<param name="wmode" value="window">'+
                '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">'+
                '<param name="flashvars"value="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs="{{songId}}"&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0">'+
                '<embed src="{{src}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"width="{{width}}"height="{{height}}"flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&amp;songIDs="{{songId}}"&amp;style=metal&amp;p=0" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="window"/>'+
            '</object>'
    }
})
```

Then pass your data into the directive in your view:

```
<flash-widget width='250' height='40' src='http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf' songID='{{bpmSong[0].$id}}' ></flash>
```

Comment: that isnt working but i think that is what I am looking for I am updating my question with more code so you can see what I am working with

Comment: Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string at the template line

Comment: close! 
Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression

Comment: I can't help without seeing the whole code. Have a read of Dan Wahlins guide for directives http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals

Comment: ok ill take a look at the guide.  That is my entire code the only thing i didnt add was an angular.constant with my full firebase url